# Desperate for NSXMLParser Guidance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I previously asked this question [XMLParser Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392089/xmlparser-advice).

However I am still unable to get it to function properly....

So I guess I will start from scratch:

Located at a certain URL is an XML Tree that looks like this

```
<result>

   //stuff that I dont need

   <title>
      //thing that I do need
   </title>

  //stuff that I dont need

   <body>
      //thing that I do need
   </body>

<result>
```

How the heck do I go about parsing that?
The (useless) code I have so far can be found in the link at the top of this question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLParser Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392089/xmlparser-advice)

Comment: Don't just repost a question. You should edit your original to make it clearer if necessary, this will also bump it to the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a simple class, which will be the parser's delegate.

```
@interface YourObject : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSString *title, *body;    // object attributes
    NSXMLParser *parser;       // will parse XML
    NSMutableString *strData;  // will contains string data being parsed
}

@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *title, body;

// will be used to set your object attributes
-(void)fetchValuesAtURL:(NSString *)url;

@end
```

The `fetchValuesAtURL:` method will initiate the parse operation.

```
@implementation YourObject

@synthesize title, body;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        title = @"";
        body = @"";
        parser = nil;
        strData = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)fetchValuesAtURL:(NSString *)url {
    if(parser) {
        [parser release];
    }
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    // element is about to be parsed, clean the mutable string
    [strData setString:@""];
}

// the probably missing method
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    // content (or part of) has been found, append that to the current string
    [strData appendString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
   didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    // element has been parsed, test the element name
    // and store strData accordingly
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        self.title = strData;
    }
    else {    // or else if, here you got two elements to parse
        self.body = strData;
    }
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [body release];
    [strData release];
    if(parser) {
        [parser release];
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then :

```
YourObject *obj = [[YourObject alloc] init];
[obj fetchValuesAtURL:@"http://www.site.com/xml/url"];
```

`NSXMLParser`'s delegate is able to do many more things, as described in [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) from Apple.
For complete reference on delegate methods, see [NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You are making a synchronous call which will block the current thread. initWithContentsOfURL is meant to be used for files within application bundle.

Comment: @0x8badf00d - that is good point. The example is still valid as NSXMLParser guidance I think.